# Combining multiple par plots in one big graph

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I'm currently working on functional analysis in R using the fda.oce package ([link here](https://github.com/EPauthenet/fda.oce)). There is one function in this package that allows to plot profiles according to the functional PCA results together:

```
eigen_plot_bigger <- function (pca, te, sign = 1) 
{
  nbas = pca$nbas
  ndim = pca$ndim
  basis = pca$basis
  Cm = pca$Cm
  prange = basis$rangeval
  depth = prange[1]:prange[2]
  par(mfrow = c(1, ndim), oma = c(0, 0, 2, 0), mar = c(4.1, 
                                                       4.1, 0.5, 0.35))
  for (k in 1:ndim) {
    d = ((k - 1) * nbas + 1):(k * nbas)
    pb = round(100 * sum(pca$vecnotWM[d, te]^2), 0)
    fdobj_vp = fd(Cm[d] + sign * pca$axe[d, te], pca$basis, 
                  pca$fdnames)
    fdobj_vm = fd(Cm[d] - sign * pca$axe[d, te], pca$basis, 
                  pca$fdnames)
    fdobj_m = fd(Cm[d], pca$basis, pca$fdnames)
    vp = eval.fd(depth, fdobj_vp)
    vm = eval.fd(depth, fdobj_vm)
    prof_m = eval.fd(depth, fdobj_m)
    plot(prof_m, depth, typ = "l", xlab = paste(pca$fdnames[[k + 
                                                               2]], " (", pb, " %)", sep = ""), ylab = pca$fdnames[[1]], 
         xlim = range(vp, vm, prof_m), ylim = c(prange[2], 
                                                prange[1]), yaxs = "i", las = 1, 
         lwd = 3)
    lines(vp, depth, col = 2, lwd = 3)
    lines(vm, depth, col = 4, lwd = 3)
  }
  mtext(paste("PC", te, " (", round(pca$pval[te], 0), " %)", 
              sep = ""), outer = TRUE, cex = 1.5)
}
```

The output of this function produces this graph thanks to the `par(mfrow = c(1, ndim)` since I have 2 variables in this analysis (temperature and salinity):
[image: Output of the function]

However, it is only for one principal component (here, the first), where I have 4 of them I'd like to plot into a single graph, just like below (I made the graph below using powerpoint):

[image]

Thing is, if I do a `par(mfrow = c(2,2)` to split my window in 4, the `par(mfrow = c(1, ndim)` included in the `eigen_plot_bigger` cancels the new one and I have each principal component plot on a individual page.

```
pdf("./Océano et ACP fonctionnelle/Figures/Reconstruction profils fPCA.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in 1:4){
  eigen_plot_bigger(pca,i)
  legend(x="bottomright",legend = c("+1", "-1"), 
         col = c("red","blue"),lty=c(1,1))
}
dev.off()
```

I would like to know if there is a way I can combine these 4 graphs directly in R by contourning the `par()` command? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think that if you remove the `par()` command from the function (or at least the `mfrow=` part of it) and use `par(mfrow=c(4, 4))` when producing the PDF, you should generally get what you want. You will only have to deal with the PCA titles produced by the `mtext()` command which won't be positioned correctly anymore. If you made your code reproducible, I could be more specific, but at the moment I don't know how to produce the `pca` object.